# Structural Building design software for civil structural engineers/learners

Tags: windows, scientific-computing

Suppose I'm a structural engineer, who knows the basic concepts such as deflection, sagging, hogging, tension, compression, shear force, etc. I need to provide structural details to my client who want to build a 4 story office building. Nowadays, structural engineers do not calculate the beam size, how much steel bars (reinforcement needed) by hand. They just use software to get those out puts. They just feed the area, beam lengths, weight (Kilo Newtons), and software calculates the entire structure and determines basic things like deflection, tension, compression for you and provides you with the necessary concrete strength grade  & reinforcement details for the entire structure. I need that kind of software. Commercial paid software are ok with me. Any recommendations.

Comment: If you want your software to go beyond structural analysis to design questions like reinforcement or concrete strength, you will need to specify in the question what country you are in, because a lot of if depend on applicable building codes, and programs are usually based on a specific country and code.